# Таблица стилей загружается не полностью

Tags: css, веб-программирование, asp.net

Во время запуска приложения в Visual Studio страницы отображаются нормально, всё работает. При публикации приложения загружается не весь файл .css, а только 54 строчки из 81

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По какой причине часть кода игнорируется и как это можно исправить?

Comment: Проверьте на синтаксические ошибки ваш файл.

Comment: Если бы они были, то в Visual Studio то же бы не отображалось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно обновить страницу: CTRL+F5